# IIS 10 new website with custom port number can't be accessed from Internet

Tags: iis, iis-10

So I deployed a new website in IIS 10 with port number 8888 (the Default Web Site uses port 80).

[image]

I can successfully browse the website locally on the server. However, I can't visit it from another PC using Internet. The browser complains 'Hmmm.. can't reach this page'.

The firewall on server has been manually shut down.

[image]

I also checked that port 8888 is listening on my server.

[image]

Did I miss any steps here?

Comment: What address are you using to access the page from the other machine? Do you need to access the site from _outside_ your local network?

Comment: @RichardSzalay Yeah, the server is on cloud, so I need other people to visit the website from Internet (outside of the local network the server is in). I used 'http://(server IP address):8888/' to visit the website from another PC.

Comment: If this is a VM in a public cloud, you should make it very clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

All right, I got it work... Turns out the cloud service that I use shut down accesses to almost all ports except port 80 by default... After I open port 8888 on the cloud settings, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @NJUHOBBY is right, I use **Google Cloud** and I had to go over

```
Google Cloud Console -> VPC Networks -> Firewall Rules -> Create Firewall Rule
```

...to create a new rule. Please be aware that Firewall Rules are applied to VM through TAGS, so if you choose to use https-server tag this rule will apply to all your VM's (this is tag is assigned to all server instances by default). In my case I set a custom tag and then I added this tag to my VM like this:

```
Compute Engines-> VM Instances.
```

Then I clicked my server's vm name and clicked Edit then I added the custom tag in the appropriate field. After saving VM's properties, the port was successfully opened.